# How to change language in mapbox leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

**Aim to create this post is, didn't find any answer for it or any question about change language of mapbox js or leaflet, i can see only solution for GL JS.**

I am using mapbox js or leaflet and i want to change language of map.

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var mapOne = L.mapbox.map("map").setView([center_lng, center_lat], 4).addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'));
var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(mapOne);
```

How to change language of mapbox map by using this library?

Comment: Take a look into: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/232877

Comment: The short version is: you can't dynamically change labels to different language using raster tiles in Leaflet.